# Incorrect uninitialized variable warning inside macro

Tags: c, macros, warnings

I have a macro that is used in my code that wraps function calls and checks the return codes. The macro is pretty simple:

```
#define CALL_POP(FUNC)                                  \
   do                                                   \
   {                                                    \
       my_errno = FUNC;                                 \
       if (unlikely(my_errno != SUCCESS)) goto fn_exit; \
   } while (0)
```

However, when compiling with `-Wall` and `-O3`, my compiler (GCC 5.3.1) complains about an uninitialized variable:

```
filename.h:194:10: warning: 'my_errno' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
   if (unlikely(my_errno!=SUCCESS)) goto fn_exit; \
      ^
```

This seems weird since the variable is clearly initialized on the line before and is declared elsewhere (before calling this macro).

Here's an example of calling this macro:

```
  int my_errno;

  CALL_POP(send
      (&ctrl, NULL, 0, recv->remote_info.origin_rank, 
       recv->comm_ptr, recv->remote_info.ackreq, FALSE));

  ...

fn_exit:
  return my_errno;
```

Does anyone have ideas as to why it's complaining about my usage here?

Comment: How do you use this macro? (MCVE?)

Comment: As EugeneSh. said it would be useful to see how you use that macro to see what `FUNC` will be.

Comment: I've added an example usage to the question. I'm working on getting a cut down MCVE that I can post easily. If the example above isn't enough to be helpful, I can keep working on that.

Comment: How `my_errno` is defined? BTW, you are saying it is an example of the call. Is it the only way it is called? Or there any other ways?

Comment: Sorry, meant to add that part. Clarified again.

Comment: This is weird that the compiler is complaining about the code within the macro itself. Can you make a full MCVE? BTW, `send` is returning `ssize_t`, not `int`. Could `FUNC` be defined elsewhere?

Comment: Perhaps there's some other contextual issue. I tried putting your macro and usage into a simple `.c` program file and I didn't see the warning about `my_errno`.

Comment: Yeah, I'll have to keep working on an MVCE to reproduce this. Trying to cut down ~200k. :)

Comment: 1) Same problem with `send
      (&ctrl, NULL, 0, recv->remote_info.origin_rank, 
       recv->comm_ptr, recv->remote_info.ackreq, FALSE)` substituted with `rand()`?  2) is `unlikely()` a simple function?   3) Is this the _only_ `CALL_POP()` 4) Make `...` nothing.

Comment: `unlikely()` is the same as the Linux kernel definition. It's probably not important here. When I finish the MVCE, I'll drop all of that.

Comment: `unlikely` is a macro. Shouldn't be a problem though.

Answer (score -2):

I believe you're missing some escaping, to escape the newline after the macro name,

something like

```
#define CALL_POP(FUNC) \
do { \
// stuff \
do_stuff() \
}while(0);
```

Comment: with a newline after the '\' escaping character, this code formatting stuff is odd

Comment: Hm. What? Everything is fine here.